# How to download an https live stream m3u8 file on mac?

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

How do I download an m3u8 file from live streaming source on a mac. I do not want to lose any frame or bitrate or compromise on quality at all. I want audio and video to be in perfect sync like they are on the browser and want to save file as mkv or mpv extension. I browsed the internet and found out about ffmpeg but I do not know the exact way to do that without compromising on quality

Would really love any help here

Comment: `ffmpeg -i https://example.com/stream.m3u8 -codec copy output.mkv`  This will usually get what you want... the representation with the best quality.  (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Automatic-stream-selection)  You can also use `-map` if  you need to get multiple for some reason.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.